# Ruby puts Displaying nil in rescue

Tags: ruby, null, rescue, puts

I am brand new to Ruby and am coming from a Python background.  To help learn the language, I'm porting an existing Python script so I can do a side by side comparison.  Thus far, I have a small bit of code and am confused as to why 'nil' prints to the console.  Code below:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
require 'date'

backup_dirs = ['/backups/db', '/backups/log']

backup_dirs.each do |backup_dir|
  Dir.glob(backup_dir + '/' + '*.*.*.*.*.*').each do |filename|
    begin
      creation_date = DateTime.strptime(filename.split('.')[3], '%m%d%Y%H%M')
    rescue
      puts "Skipping #{filename}, invalid file."
    end
  end
    puts 'File is okay.'
end
```

If the `DateTime.strptime` method throws an exception, `rescue` runs and `puts` prints out the string fine.  Except, after it comes a `nil`.  I "googled" and found that `puts` returns `nil`.  But why does that show only in the `rescue` area and not in the `File is okay.` line.

I.e. an example `rescue` output would be:

```
Skipping /backups/log/fs.server.dir.999999999999.14.log, invalid file.
nil
```

And, how do I make it stop displaying that to the console?  I'm sure this is a fundamental language thing, just very new to the language so any insight would be much appreciated.

Thanks - Tom

Comment: Could you give more details on how do you run this code? Do you copy/paste it into console?

Comment: Hi sorry... left out the details.  I'm just running this on the command line of a Linux server, through an SSH session... not through IRB or anything.

Comment: Still cannot reproduce. Is that the complete code, or is it just a snippet? `nil`s never show up in the output unless you tell it (and you have to really want to see nil there, as `puts nil` will print empty line)

Comment: BroiSatse ... I'm a dork, sorry :-( ... I figured it out.  In the actual code, I was printing the value of creation_date not saying 'File is okay' ... it was that `puts` that was printing `nil` as it very well should have been!  Sorry... first day playing with this language.  Thanks so much for the help and trying to duplicate the issue.

Comment: (Not about the nil) I think you need to insert a `next` statement after the `puts "skipping...` line, actually skipping the invalid file.

Comment: steenslag... You are correct, that's exactly what I ended up doing.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is expected behavior.  Ruby methods will return the last statement evaluated if `return whatever` is not specified.

In the sample you have provided you are ending with a `puts` statement.

`puts` writes your output then returns `nil` and subsequently your method returns `nil`

From irb just run the following two statements to see this in action.

`puts 'foo'`

`'foo'`

Comment: However in this case the return value should be `backup_dirs` array, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 1):

All... sorry.  I figured this out.  In the actual code I was doing a `puts creation_date` and that is what was causing the `nil` to show... as it very well should!

First day learning the language, oops!  Did learn a lot about `puts` though... appreciate all of the answers, sorry for wasting everyones' time.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually because of the [#puts](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/IO.html#method-i-puts) method you're calling.

**puts(obj, ...) → nil**

> Writes the given objects to ios as with IO#print. Writes a record separator (typically a
>   newline) after any that do not already end with a newline sequence. If
>   called with an array argument, writes each element on a new line. If
>   called without arguments, outputs a single record separator.
>
> $stdout.puts("this", "is", "a", "test") produces:
>
> this is a test

You can check that in pry/irb:

```
[9] pry(main)> puts "Hello"
Hello
=> nil
```

Comment: Thanks.  I get it that `puts` returns `nil`.  And I know we can see those when using `irb`.  However, why would the `puts` in `rescue` show `nil` and the regular one does not?  (This is running in a standard SSH session on Linux box).  And, is there ia standard way of muting the `nil` so it doesn't show?  Thanks again for the help.

Comment: Sorry.. figured it out, my mistake, wrote details in my answer!